# Conversion issue in dtsx package

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a dtsx package that does a data conversion task and import into SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  I am having an inconsistent problem with a user, and since I am unable to change their behavior, I would like to avoid the problem.  I have a column in an Excel worksheet that is created by the client.  The column is a comment field.  On a number of occasions, they have chosen to simply enter a numeric or currency value into the comment cell.  I have suggested that they use their words but my requests have not been well received.  What I need to do is have the package disregard what it is seeing and treat it as a string field regardless.  When I have a normal string in the cell, the system operates as expected.  I have tried doing a conversion to an unicode string(DT_WSTR), unicode text stream (DT_NEXT) and string (DT_STR).

If there is additional information I should provide I would appreciate knowing and I will endeavor to get it.

This is the first time I have done a dtsx package for this purpose, I have done mostly moves and deletes up to this point.

Comment: have you tried using IMEX in your connect string - look up IMEX and Excel and you'll find lots of examples. Forget about tying to change business process or trying to get Excel data clean.

Answer (score 0):

In the Excel Source Data Source, I would change the Data access mode to SQL Command.  Then I would write a SELECT statement using `CStr ( dodgy_comment) AS comment` etc.  Note that column names need to be enclosed in back-quotes `.